# Royalmail api token X-RMG-Security parameters

Tags: api, royalmail

I try create token to Royal Mail Api

https://developer.royalmail.net/node/1877912

```
 curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.royalmail.net/shipping/v3/token \
  --header 'X-IBM-Client-Id: clientId' \
  --header 'X-IBM-Client-Secret: clientSecret' \
  --header 'X-RMG-Security-Password: mypass' \
  --header 'X-RMG-Security-Username: myuser@gmail.com' \
  --header 'accept: application/json'
```

get response

```
{ "httpCode":"401", "httpMessage":"Unauthorized", "moreInformation":"Invalid client id or secret." }
```

myuser@gmail.com and mypass - is working  details to login to https://developer.royalmail.net/user/login

clientId clientSecret is copied from my aps in royam mail

i also try urlencode myuser@gmail.com , same result.

so what is X-RMG-Security-Username and X-RMG-Security-Password ?